# Выбор файлов на htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Можно ли в `.htaccess` реализовать следующее?

Если обращаются с доменa **wap.site.com** , то файлы берутся с папки **/pages/wap/** (этот вариант сейчас реализован)

Если обращаются с домена **site.com**, то файлы берутся с папки **/pages/web/** , но если в папке **/pages/web/** нет подходящего файла, то файл берется с папки **/pages/wap/**

Новенький в `htaccess` и даже понятия не имею как такое реализовать и возможно ли это. Просто я сделал wap-версию сайта, а веб только начинаю, хочу открыть её и разрабатывать понемногу веб-версии страниц, ну а пока нет страниц, то пусть будет с wap-версии.

Comment: Точнее: первый вариант реализован, хочу реализовать второй ещё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/web/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wap.site.com # Это можно не учитивать, 
# так как если нет в папке /pages/web но переводим в /pages/wap/

# если нет это директории
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# если нет этого файла
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /pages/wap/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш код почти работал. Я немного внёс коррективы, ибо перенаправляло на /pages/wap/pages/$1 .
Теперь этот код работает отлично:

          RewriteEngine on

          RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/web/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

          # если нет это директории
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         # если нет этого файла
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$  /pages/wap/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: получается в ссылке у вас участвует `pages/` из этого у вас пришлось изменить. согласен, спасибо